# Fresh installation gets 403 error when non-administrator user tries to access a page

Tags: wordpress, error

I've just made a fresh installation of Wordpress/CiviCRM, followed installation instructions and hope to have installation requirements fully satisfied. I can get access to the dashboard and everything looks fine when I log in as administrative privileges, but when using another user to login (with Wordpress "Editor" priviliges for example), i get a 403 errore while trying to access the dashboard. What could be wrong in my setup?

I also have another question: which is the default URL I could give my users to access the dashboard? should I give them https:///wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM or does exists by default another path like https:///civicrm/dashboard ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

What do you have at `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Faccess%2Fwp-permissions&reset=1`? You probably just need to set up permissions.

More info here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/

Comment: unfortunately this seems not to be the problem. There must be a mistake I made...thanks a lot anyway :)

Comment: I see that somehow this depends on the ISP hosting my CiviCRM instance. Trying elsewhere a fresh installation works as expected.